# What model is most appropriate to estimate the probability of something occurring?

Tags: probability, self-study

e.g. estimate the probability that of 10 (ten) small businesses 3 (three) or less will fail in the first year of operation

Comment: Without more information, it may be difficult to give a clear cut answer. Is there any information about business failure in the area, ie: how is the failure of businesses distributed in the area?

Comment: @ChristopherAden it is just a random selection of a much larger group of small businesses - if that makes sense.

Comment: That clarification helps quite a lot, but it's still short of what @Christopher is looking for.  If *every* business has the same chance of failing and failures are independent, the binomial model of Karl Broman's reply is appropriate.  But if the chances of failure vary--which they surely do in any realistic situation--you need a two-stage ("compound") model to handle the [overdispersion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdispersion).  Moreover, as Peter Flom points out, the failures (*definitely*) are not independent: external ("exogenous") conditions influence all businesses simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be no single model "to estimate the probability of something occurring".  You need to specify precisely what is the something, and then describe the nature of the process that leads it to occur or not.

For your specific example, if the 10 businesses each have equal chances of failing, and if the failure or not of the businesses are independent, then you could model these like 10 draws from a deck of red and black cards, where red represents failure.  Then the number of failing businesses would follow a binomial distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the events occur independently of each other, I would suggest a [Poisson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process) Process.

If the events are conditioned on a state or regime then a Markov model would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Several people have noted what to do if the events are independent, and if you  know what the probability of each event is.

If this is a real world problem, however, I'd caution against assuming that they events are independent. That makes the problem harder, but more realistic.

Comment: So, what are some possible approaches for the non-independent case?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of businesses failing, you might be interested in reading up on something called joint probability of default models. These are statistical models used in finance to value structured deals, like the famous mortgage CDOs that popped in '07. The model that is most "standard" (i.e. the least sophisticated) is the Gaussian copula model. You will see how in this model there is a common market factor (a single factor) that drives the defaults of all businesses. This could be a good "baseline" for you to start from in modeling the failure of a particular number of businesses in a particular area, for example.